# Getting object from list by attribute

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm new with spring boot and I'm stuck on this.

I have a list of objects and I want to check if one of its attributes are equal to another variable and if it does, I want to get that object. All I can do is checking to see if the list contains an object with that attribute. I cannot retrieve the actual  object.

Not sure how to move on from here

```
<p th:if="${list.contains(n)}"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's all about Thymeleaf [Attribute Precedence](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#attribute-precedence). For your list, you would use `th:each` to loop through objects and `th:if` to conditionally filter the current iteration object from the list. As long as condition match, you've got your object and able to access it's properties. So your code may look like ...

```
<p th:each="yourObject: ${list}" th:if="${list.contains(n)}" th:text="${yourObject.yourProperty}">Your Object's property is here only when condition met</p>
```